# Oracle SQL Developer 20.4.1 - View Object Details Not Showing SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 20.4.1.407 connecting to an Oracle 11g database

I have a view in the left hand side pane which I click on once and then on the right hand side it pulls up the object details.

So I see multiple tabs

Columns - Data - Grants - Dependancies - **Details** - Triggers - **SQL** - Errors

When I click on "SQL" a pop up comes up saying "Generating DDL" then it pulls up blank

[image]

Now when I go to the "Details" tab I can see some sort of SQL in the "TEXT" field as shown

[image]

So 2 questions

- First I was wondering why doesnt the SQL just show up in the SQL tab? Is this a permissions issue with my loggged in user?
- Second if the SQL is shown in the details TEXT column why have a SQL tab at all? Whats the difference between the two spots?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't find documentation on the tabs. However, it appears the **Details** tab comes from either sys.dba_views or sys.user_views (for a database object of type VIEW). The **SQL** tab is the result of a call to dbms_metadata.get_ddl. It generates the DDL statement one would use to create the database object.

Comment: Hm - This makes me wonder if its a permission issue on the dbms_metadata.get_ddl? Since it sounds like its two different calls to seperate places. And this again makes me wonder why or what is the difference between the two places

Answer (score 1):

For a view, this is most likely a privileges issue.

For example, if I logon as SCOTT on my database, I can click on views in the SYS schema and see their Details, eg

[image]

But if click DDL, then I'll get a blank because I don't have privileges to query the contents of the view or its definition.

Views are an "odd" case, because the DDL is virtually synonymous with the data in ALL_VIEWS.TEXT_VC.

Sidenote: SQL Dev 20 is long in the tooth. Its trivial to upgrade so why not head over to SQL Dev 22.

Comment: This is indeed an odd one because actually I can query the view and see the view data contents no problem. If I could not even query/view the data then ok I can see maybe I wouldnt be able to see the DDL for the view. So I dont think its a permission issue on the VIEW itself as I am able to query/view the data. Similar to you I can see in the "Details" pane the "TEXT VC" which looks like its the view query. But I was still just wondering whats the difference between "TEXT VC" and the "SQL" tab showing up blank. Are you logged on as a DBA on your Scott Schema? Just curious

Comment: Side note: I did upgrade my SQL Developer and still have the same issue. So its not a version issue, but I do appreciate the nudge to keep my tools up to date :)